issue while trying to create a new angular project within the existing development tree
so i already installed angular in node.js while using the command npm install -g @angular/cli.
Then I tried to create a new Angular application using the command so that i can create a new tree within the existing development tree.

PS C:\travlr> ng new travlr-admin --defaults=true --skipGit=true --skipTests=true --directory app_admin

But I am getting this error

Error: Unknown arguments: skipGit, skipTests

Then, I tried using this commands

ng new travlr-admin --defaults=true --skipGit=true --skip-Tests --directory app_admin
ng new travlr-admin --defaults=true --skipGit=true --skipTests --directory app_admin

Both fails. What's wrong with the commands?

It's dash-case: --skip-git and --skip-tests. full command: ng new travlr-admin --defaults --skip-git--skip-tests --directory=app_admin
